# Why Multer does not release memory?

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, multer

I am developing **node** application to **upload** files, I can see that when **multer** receives a request with file **200KB** for example, it then holds **400KB** in the memory and does not release it even after the request finishes until the app receives a new request and do the same with the next request.

[![Memory Usage][1]][1]

````
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});


const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;

app.use(express.json());

app.post("/submitRequest", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  return res.send('ok')
});


const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on https://localhost:${port}`);
});

console.log('Server started at:', new Date().toLocaleString()); ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFyEb.png
````

Comment: How are you determining when the memory is "released"?'  Are you looking at total process memory or something more granular within nodejs?

Comment: I am looking at the total memory used by the application which should be only some megabytes running by the application and the file that is sent when the request is being processed then it returns to the normal state; however, what happens is that the memory consumes double the file size and does not release it as in the screenshoot https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFyEb.png.

Comment: You will have to look at the actual nodejs heap snapshots before/after to understand better what is going on.  There is no requirement that nodejs will return back to the OS every single piece of memory that is freed by the GC.  Some memory remains in the heap waiting to be reused by future allocations.

Comment: All that should really matter to you is that there is no leaking.  Memory does not continue to go up and up and up continuously after repeated requests.